# Colorizing your terminal and shell environment?

Tags: shell, bash, colors, prompt

I spend most of my time working in Unix environments and using terminal emulators. I try to use color on the command line, because color makes the output more useful and intuitive.

What options exist to add color to my terminal environment? What tricks do you use? What pitfalls have you encountered?

Unfortunately, support for color varies depending on terminal type, OS, TERM setting, utility, buggy implementations, etc.

Here are some tips from my setup, after a lot of experimentation:

1. I tend to set `TERM=xterm-color`, which is supported on most hosts (but not all).
2. I work on a number of different hosts, different OS versions, etc. I use everything from macOS X, Ubuntu Linux, RHEL/CentOS/Scientific Linux and FreeBSD. I'm trying to keep things simple and generic, if possible.
3. I do a bunch of work using GNU `screen`, which adds another layer of fun.
4. Many OSs set things like `dircolors` and by default, and I don't want to modify this on a hundred different hosts. So I try to stick with the defaults. Instead, I tweak my terminal's color configuration.
5. Use color for some [Unix commands](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch09.en.html#_colorized_commands) (`ls`, `grep`, `less`, `vim`) and the [Bash prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/). These commands seem to use the standard "[ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)". For example:

   ```
   alias less='less --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS'
   export LS_OPTS='--color=auto'
   alias ls='ls ${LS_OPTS}'
   ```

I'll post my `.bashrc` and answer my own question Jeopardy Style.

Comment: fyi my approach (see answer below) addresses issues with OSX and Linux differences, for example color on one is ls -G and on the other is ls --color-auto

Comment: Did anybody see a tool to color columns? That is a `column -t --color`?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek have you looked into grc ?

Comment: It is generally a very poor idea to set TERM manually.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108410/is-it-correct-to-set-the-term-variable-manually

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Here are a couple of things you can do:

**Editors + Code**
A lot of editors have syntax highlighting support. `vim` and `emacs` have it on by default. You can also [enable it under `nano`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano).

You can also syntax highlight code on the terminal by using [Pygments](http://pygments.org/faq/#how-can-i-use-pygments) as a command-line tool.

**grep**
`grep --color=auto` highlights all matches. You can also use `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` to make it persistent without an alias. If you use `--color=always`, it'll [use colour even when piping](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2007/10/grep-with-color-output.html), which confuses things.

**ls**

`ls --color=always`

Colors specified by:

```
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33'
```

(hint: `dircolors` can be helpful)

**PS1**
You can set your PS1 (shell prompt) to use colours. For example:

```
PS1='\e[33;1m\u@\h: \e[31m\W\e[0m\$ '
```

Will produce a PS1 like:

[yellow]lucas@ubuntu: [red]~[normal]$

You can get really creative with this. As an idea:

```
PS1='\e[s\e[0;0H\e[1;33m\h    \t\n\e[1;32mThis is my computer\e[u[\u@\h:  \w]\$ '
```

Puts a bar at the top of your terminal with some random info. (For best results, also use `alias clear="echo -e '\e[2J\n\n'"`.)

**Getting Rid of Escape Sequences**

If something is stuck outputting colour when you don't want it to, I use this `sed` line to strip the escape sequences:

```
sed "s/\[^[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//gi"
```

If you want a more authentic experience, you can also get rid of lines starting with `\e[8m`, which instructs the terminal to hide the text. (Not widely supported.)

```
sed "s/^\[^[8m.*$//gi"
```

Also note that those ^[s should be actual, literal ^[s. You can type them by pressing ^V^[ in bash, that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: The first PS1 line should read like this: `PS1='\e[33;1m\u@\h: \e[31m\W\e[0m\$ '`. There is a superfluous x after the fourth backslash.

Comment: Escapes should be enclosed in `\[...\]` or else commands in second line will overwrite the first line. PS1='\[\e[33;1m\]\u@\h: \[\e[31m\]\W\e[0m\$ '

Comment: The `ls --color=always` doesn't work. @Michael Durrant' s approach is better for this: `ls --color=al > /dev/null 2>&1 && alias ls='ls -F --color=al' || alias ls='ls -G'`

Answer (score 109):

I also use:

```
export TERM=xterm-color
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto' GREP_COLOR='1;32'
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

And if you like colorizing your prompt, defined color vars can be useful:

```
export COLOR_NC='\e[0m' # No Color
export COLOR_BLACK='\e[0;30m'
export COLOR_GRAY='\e[1;30m'
export COLOR_RED='\e[0;31m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_RED='\e[1;31m'
export COLOR_GREEN='\e[0;32m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
export COLOR_BROWN='\e[0;33m'
export COLOR_YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
export COLOR_BLUE='\e[0;34m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE='\e[1;34m'
export COLOR_PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE='\e[1;35m'
export COLOR_CYAN='\e[0;36m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN='\e[1;36m'
export COLOR_LIGHT_GRAY='\e[0;37m'
export COLOR_WHITE='\e[1;37m'
```

And then my prompt is something like this:

```
case $TERM in
     xterm*|rxvt*)
         local TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u ${NEW_PWD}\007\]'
          ;;
     *)
         local TITLEBAR=""
          ;;
    esac

local UC=$COLOR_WHITE               # user's color
[ $UID -eq "0" ] && UC=$COLOR_RED   # root's color

PS1="$TITLEBAR\n\[${UC}\]\u \[${COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE}\]\${PWD} \[${COLOR_BLACK}\]\$(vcprompt) \n\[${COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN}\]→\[${COLOR_NC}\] "
```

$(vcprompt) is calling a python script in my ~/sbin which prints version control information about the current path.  It includes support for Mercurial, Git, Svn, Cvs, etc.  The author of the script has the [source here](https://gist.github.com/kriswill/83c1aad72b961632866fc012f2578dea).

[image: Bash prompt screenshot]

This is the [full source](https://github.com/kriswill/dotfiles/blob/legacy/bash/prompt) of my prompt configuration:

Comment: See here for the solution to a line problem I got when I used the above PS1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087036/bashrc-break-second-line-entered-in-shell-eats-up-first-line

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the escaped brackets for the colors in the prompt.  Thanks!

Comment: `$LSCOLORS` and `$CLICOLOR` are for BSD ls.  GNU ls (Linux) uses `$LS_COLORS` with a different syntax.  As GNU feels like home to me, I use `LSCOLORS=exgxfxDacxBaBaCaCaeaEa` to mimic GNU's colors on BSD.

Comment: `grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script`

Comment: A screenshot would be nice

Comment: Update on `$LSCOLORS` GNU parity: `LSCOLORS=ExGxFxDaCxDaDaxbxDacad`.

Comment: Your values are the same for `COLOR_BLACK` and `COLOR_GREY`.

Comment: Any fork or alternative links for the `vcprompt`? Seems like it's now a 404.

Comment: Added a new link to the source for `vcprompt` as a GitHub gist, and a screen capture of the colorized final prompt.

Comment: You may need to source the `.bashrc` file for the modification to be effective. You can do it with the following command.

`source /path/to/.bashrc`

Answer (score 20):

`grep` and `ls` have already been mentioned, if you want a lot more colors check out [Generic Coloriser](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html), its initial purpose was to colorize logfiles, but right out of the box it also colorizes `ping`, `traceroute`, `gcc`, `make`, `netstat`, `diff`, `last`, `ldap`, and `cvs`.

It's easily extended if you know regexes. I've added `ps` and `nmap` to the list (if you get into `grc` I'll be more than glad to share the .conf files for those two tools)

(Btw, to install it via `synaptic`, `pacman`, and alike you might have better luck searching for "grc")

Comment: `grc` now supports `ps` by default.  I'd be interested in your `nmap` colorings.  See also my answer for aliasing all of these in a way that will absorb new commands when you upgrade grc.

Comment: I noticed that. here's my conf.nmap (and everything else, really) https://gist.github.com/sygo/844982#file-conf-nmap - I noticed you work in infosec, you might find conf.hexdump interesting, I haven't finished it yet though.

Comment: Thanks @Sygo.  I've forked and revised your gist.  I've never actually committed data with git (let alone github's gists) and I cannot figure out how to propose merging it back to you (I'm guessing this is because gists are too simplified).

Comment: I suspect you can't because it's a gist and not a proper repository. I did check out your fork though and I'm definitely giving your version a go. I'm curious as what that hex dump one will turn into...

Answer (score 18):

I've honed my .bashrc over the years to work on both OSX and Ubuntu.
I've also reduced it in size to 28 lines with compact condition statements.
With it, my PS1 prompt looks like:
[image]

with time in red, username in green, machine name in light blue, pwd in darker blue and git branch in yellow.

Feature of my PS1 prompt:

- shows git branch!
- long directory paths (more than 6 elements) are 'trimmed' to show top 3 and bottom 3 directories with `_` between then (that's the `pwd sed` part of LOCATION).
- carriage return at the end so that prompt is always on the left!

The relevant lines from my `.bashrc` file are:

```
git_branch () { git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'; }
HOST='\033[02;36m\]\h'; HOST=' '$HOST
TIME='\033[01;31m\]\t \033[01;32m\]'
LOCATION=' \033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"`'
BRANCH=' \033[00;33m\]$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS1=$TIME$USER$HOST$LOCATION$BRANCH
PS2='\[\033[01;36m\]>'
```

For ls with colors when available and no errors when not (i.e. OSX):

```
ls --color=al > /dev/null 2>&1 && alias ls='ls -F --color=al' || alias ls='ls -G'
```

Comment: Colors are available for `ls` on OS X, but it is done by using `export CLICOLOR=1`.

Comment: @ThomasW but not on linux :-p The guy uses both.

Comment: Nonetheless, ThomasW is correct to point out that the answer is erroneous in saying that colours are not available with `ls` on MacOS 10.  The answer is also erroneous in that the prompt strings here are in fact faulty.  They do not [correctly balance `\[` and `\]`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317743/5132), and [have caused problems for at least one person copying this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323822/).

Answer (score 12):

Colors for **man pages** ([more detail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108699/docs-for-less-termcap-vars)):

```bsh
function _colorman() {
  env \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[1;35m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;34m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[7;40m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[1;33m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mr=$(tput rev) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mh=$(tput dim) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZN=$(tput ssubm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZV=$(tput rsubm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZO=$(tput ssupm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZW=$(tput rsupm) \
    GROFF_NO_SGR=1 \
      "$@"
}
alias man="LANG=C _colorman man"
function perldoc() { command perldoc -n less "$@" |man -l -; }
```

Colors for **grep** (`1;32` is bright green, see other posts here for other colors):

```bsh
GREP_OPTS='--color=auto'      # for aliases since $GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated
GREP_COLOR='1;32'             # (legacy) bright green rather than default red
# (new) Matching text in Selected line = green, line numbers dark yellow
GREP_COLORS="ms=${GREP_COLOR}:mc=${GREP_COLOR}:ln=33"
alias grep='grep $GREP_OPTS'
alias egrep='grep -E $GREP_OPTS'
alias fgrep='LC_ALL=C grep -F $GREP_OPTS'
```

Using `LC_ALL=C` for fgrep can provide a [140x performance boost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780500/519360)

More colors for **GNU ls**:

```bsh
# use the config at ~/.dircolors if it exists, otherwise generate anew
eval "$( dircolors --sh $(find ~/.dircolors -size +0 2>/dev/null) )"

# Usage: _ls_colors_add BASE NEW [NEW...]
# Have LS color given NEW extensions the way BASE extension is colored
_ls_colors_add() {
  local BASE_COLOR="${LS_COLORS##*:?.$1=}" NEW
  if [ "$LS_COLORS" != "$BASE_COLOR" ]; then
    BASE_COLOR="${BASE_COLOR%%:*}"
    shift
    for NEW in "$@"; do
      if [ "$LS_COLORS" = "${LS_COLORS#*.$NEW=}" ]; then
        LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS%%:}:*.$NEW=$BASE_COLOR:"
      fi
    done
  fi
  export LS_COLORS
}

_ls_colors_add zip jar xpi            # archives
_ls_colors_add jpg ico JPG PNG webp   # images
_ls_colors_add ogg opus               # audio (opus now included by default)

export CLICOLOR=1   # BSD auto-color trigger (like  ls -G  but for everything)
if ls -ld --color=auto / >/dev/null 2>&1
  then alias ls="ls -ph --color=auto"
  else alias ls="ls -ph"
fi
```

Install **`grc`** ([Generic Colouriser](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/%7Egarabik/software/grc.html)) and add it to your aliases:

```bsh
if type grc grcat >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  colourify() {  # using this as a function allows easier calling down lower
    if [[ -t 1 || -n "$CLICOLOR_FORCE" ]]
      then ${GRC:-grc} -es --colour=auto "$@"
      else "$@"
    fi
  }

  # loop through known commands plus all those with named conf files
  for cmd in g++ head ld ping6 tail traceroute6 `locate grc/conf.`; do
    cmd="${cmd##*grc/conf.}"  # we want just the command
    type "$cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1 && alias "$cmd"="colourify $cmd"
  done

  # This needs run-time detection. We even fake the 'command not found' error.
  configure() {
    if [[ -x ./configure ]]; then
      colourify ./configure "$@"
    else
      echo "configure: command not found" >&2
      return 127
    fi
  }

  unalias ll 2>/dev/null
  ll() {
    if [[ -n "$CLICOLOR_FORCE" || -t 1 ]]; then  # re-implement --color=auto
      ls -l --color=always "$@" |grcat conf.ls
      return ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${pipestatus[1]} # exit code of ls via bash or zsh
    fi
    ls -l "$@"
  }
fi
```

Colors for **diff**:  Too much content for a function, use a script and alias it in your rc file (unnecessary if you installed `grc`):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (DIFF, "-|", "diff", @ARGV) or die $!;

my $ydiff = 1;
while (<DIFF>) {
  if (not -t 1) {
    print;
    next;
  }
  chomp;
  $ydiff = 0 if /^[ <>\@+-]/ or ($. == 1 && /^\d+[a-z]{1,5}\d+$/);
  my $color = "";
  if (! $ydiff && /^[\@+-<>]/) {
    $color = (/^[<-](?!--$)/ ? 1 : /^[+>]/ ? 2 : 5);
  } elsif ($ydiff && /\t {6}([<|>])(?:\t|$)/) {
    $color = ($1 eq "<" ? 1 : $1 eq ">" ? 2 : 4);
  }
  $color ? printf ("\e[1;3%dm%s\e[0;0m\n",$color,$_) : print "$_\n";
}
close DIFF;
```

Colors for **bash prompt**:

```bsh
# Shorten home dir, Cygwin drives, paths that are too long
function PSWD() {
  local p="$*" space A B cols="${COLUMNS:-`tput cols 2>/dev/null || echo 80`}"
  p="${p/$HOME/\~}"         # shrink home down to a tilde
  if [ -d /cygdrive ] && [ "${p#/cygdrive/?/}" != "$p" ]; then
    p="${p:10:1}:${p:11}"   # /cygdrive/c/hi -> c:/hi
  fi
  space="$((${#USER}+${#HOSTNAME}+6))"  # width w/out the path
  if [ "$cols" -lt 60 ]; then echo -n "$N "; space=-29; p="$p$N\b"; fi
  if [ "$cols" -lt "$((space+${#p}+20))" ]; then # < 20 chars for the command
    A=$(( (cols-20-space)/4 ))      # a quarter of the space (-20 for cmd)
    if [ $A -lt 4 ]; then A=4; fi   # 4+ chars from beginning
    B=$(( cols-20-space-A*2 ))      # half (plus rounding) of the space
    if [ $B -lt 8 ]; then B=8; fi   # 8+ chars from end
    p="${p:0:$A}..${p: -$B}"
  fi
  echo "$p"
}

PSC() { printf $'\[\e[%sm\]' "${*:-0;0}"; }
PR="0;32"       # default color used in prompt is green
if [ "$(id -u)" = 0 ]; then
    sudo=41     # root is red background
  elif [ "$USER" != "${SUDO_USER:-$USER}" ]; then
    sudo=31     # not root, not self: red text
  else sudo="$PR"   # standard user color
fi
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ $? = 0 ] && PS1=${PS1[1]} || PS1=${PS1[2]}'
PSbase="$(PSC $sudo)\u$(PSC $PR)@\h $(PSC 33)\$(PSWD \w)"
PS1[1]="$PSbase$(PSC $PR)\$ $(PSC)"
PS1[2]="$PSbase$(PSC  31)\$ $(PSC)"
PS1="${PS1[1]}"
unset sudo PR PSbase
```

[image: demo of bash prompt]

Comment: My `PSWD()` function used to be POSIX-compatible but it's so much easier facilitated using bash/zsh substring handling.  See [revision 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/178816/6) for the POSIX version, which involves lots of question marks and wasn't at all adaptable to terminal width.  I didn't update the screenshot, but it's only a slight change at the 80 character width.

Comment: `CLICOLOR=1` doesn't work for me with FREEBSD 11.2

Comment: @SimonC. – You might be using GNU utilities on your FreeBSD system rather than the BSD ones. `CLICOLOR=1 ls` should do the same thing as `ls -G` using BSD (`ls -g` on older BSDs). If `ls --color` works (no error), you're using GNU's `ls` command and `$CLICOLOR` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks. It's really strange then. Putting `CLICOLOR=1` in my bashrc doesn't do anything, though when doing echo `$CLICOLOR` it tells me it's at when. While defining `CLICOLOR=1` just before calling `ls` as you mentioned in your post works. and `ls --color` return an "illegal option", suggesting I am indeed using BSD `ls`... not sure what's happening

Comment: @SimonC. – You have to actually load your `~/.bashrc` for any changes to take effect. Either run `source ~/.bashrc` or start a new bash session (launch a terminal or run `bash`).

Comment: yes yes I know and did (both things, starting bash again as well as source the rc file from within bash),you can see here, on my side I dont know what I am doing wrong :https://imgur.com/a/RVkUple

Comment: Maybe try running `export CLICOLOR` after you define it. If that works, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Set a bold/colored prompt. From [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/) and the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037)

```
# 'tput bold' will work regardless of the foreground and background colors.
# Place the tput output into variables, so they are only execd once.
bold=$(tput bold) # This could also be a color.
reset=$(tput sgr0)
export PS1="\u@\[$bold\]\h\[$reset\]:\w \$ "
```

I've also managed to find color settings which are widely supported, and which don't print gobbledygook characters in older environments (even FreeBSD4!), and seems to work fine if TERM=vt100, xterm, xterm-color. (For the most part). From my .bashrc:

```
# Set some options, based on the OS
OS=`uname -s` 

case "$OS" in
    "SunOS" ) 
        # Solaris ls doesn't allow color, so use special characters
        LS_OPTS='-F'
        alias  ls='ls ${LS_OPTS}'
        ;;
    "Linux" )
        # GNU ls supports colors!
        # See dircolors to customize colors
        export LS_OPTS='--color=auto' 
        alias  ls='ls ${LS_OPTS}'

        # Get color support for 'less'
        export LESS="--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS"

        # Use colors for less, man, etc.
        [[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ]] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP

        export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=auto"

        ;;
    "Darwin"|"FreeBSD")

        # Most FreeBSD & Apple Darwin supports colors
        export CLICOLOR=true
        # Get color support for 'less'
        export LESS="--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS"

        # Use colors for less, man, etc.
        [[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ]] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP

        export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=auto"
        ;;
    * ) 
        echo "Unknown OS [$OS]"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Or if you want to use ZSH, Phil Gold's prompt at http://aperiodic.net/phil/prompt/ is a work of art.

Answer (score 7):

Things that have not been said already here:

To colorize the output of your compilations with gcc, there is colorgcc by Johannes Schlüter

To colorize logs, there is multitail

To colorize any stdout, I put together [xcol](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/23/colorize-your-stdout-with-xcol/)

[image: xcol example]

I personally use these from the xcol tool.

```
#normal=$(tput sgr0)                      # normal text
normal=$'\e[0m'                           # (works better sometimes)
bold=$(tput bold)                         # make colors bold/bright
red="$bold$(tput setaf 1)"                # bright red text
green=$(tput setaf 2)                     # dim green text
fawn=$(tput setaf 3); beige="$fawn"       # dark yellow text
yellow="$bold$fawn"                       # bright yellow text
darkblue=$(tput setaf 4)                  # dim blue text
blue="$bold$darkblue"                     # bright blue text
purple=$(tput setaf 5); magenta="$purple" # magenta text
pink="$bold$purple"                       # bright magenta text
darkcyan=$(tput setaf 6)                  # dim cyan text
cyan="$bold$darkcyan"                     # bright cyan text
gray=$(tput setaf 7)                      # dim white text
darkgray="$bold"$(tput setaf 0)           # bold black = dark gray text
white="$bold$gray"                        # bright white text
```

I use these variables in my scripts like so

```
echo "${red}hello ${yellow}this is ${green}coloured${normal}"
```

I also like this little function coloredEcho ( found on Stack Overflow )

```
function coloredEcho(){
    local exp=$1;
    local color=$2;
    if ! [[ $color =~ '^[0-9]$' ]] ; then
       case $(echo $color | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') in
        black) color=0 ;;
        red) color=1 ;;
        green) color=2 ;;
        yellow) color=3 ;;
        blue) color=4 ;;
        magenta) color=5 ;;
        cyan) color=6 ;;
        white|*) color=7 ;; # white or invalid color
       esac
    fi
    tput setaf $color;
    echo $exp;
    tput sgr0;
}

coloredEcho "This text is green" green
```

Sorry, not allowed to post more links

Comment: Hello, how do you make the flags, for the prompt path? I am mentioning the rectangular bars with triangle ends Thanks

Comment: does it work in a ubuntu gnu terminal as well?

Comment: [lnav](http://lnav.org/) is also a great tool to show colorized logfiles

Answer (score 5):

There's a good tool for setting up your colours for the ls command - http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/

It provides a web-based UI to easily build your desired `$LS_COLORS` values by selecting colors:

[image: screenshot of lscolors' web page]

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you check out [ZSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) and its plugin [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) which has one of the most powerfull console features that I saw. One of them is picking theme for your terminal. This is example of my theme... In tty the colors are not so warm but they are the same like in this picture... Any way you will love it!

[image]

Comment: If I could, I would downvote this for the Oh-My-ZSH suggestion. As a systems engineer who works extensively in the Terminal, and as somebody who tried to adopt zsh/oh-my-zsh into my workflow, I can honestly say I would never recommend ZSH to anyody. Sure, you can symlink zsh to a file named after any other shell and emulate that shell, but when you do that it doesn't read your .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc. Also, you cannot put `emulate bash` in your .zprofile or .zshrc files. For anybody who works with advanced features in BASH, there are many subtleties that will bite you. BASH is a better sh.

Comment: The only thing that ZSH has out of the box that is better than BASH is command completion, but even that is programmable in BASH. Maybe somebody who doesn't use the shell except for occasional mundane tasks should adopt ZSH, but it's not for anybody who needs to use the shell extensively. the `=~` operator can bite you, the way ZSH handles arrays can bite you, etc. After using ZSH/Oh-My-ZSH for about 9 months I had enough of it. I was using a custom theme that I wrote myself, I ported it to BASH and wrote my own git promptline and I've never looked back. Now I no longer worry about portability

Comment: "it has one of the most powerfull console features that I saw. One of them is picking theme for your terminal."

Comment: @JonathanHartley, your comment looks like you left it incomplete.  ?

Comment: Thank you for your concern but my comment says everything I intended to say.

Answer (score 4):

For viewing diff output in color, use [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install colordiff
```

Pipe any diff-format output into colordiff:

[image: output of diff piped into colordiff]

This includes some of diff's alternate formats, like `-y` (side-by-side.)

Alternatively, if invoked standalone (without anything piped into it) then it acts as a wrapper around 'diff', and colors the output. Hence I have this in my .bashrc, to alias 'diff' to colordiff.

```
# if colordiff is installed, use it
if type colordiff &>/dev/null ; then
    alias diff=colordiff
```

Comment: The `.bashrc` example is missing the final `fi`, and could be converted to a single-line command: `type colordiff &> /dev/null && alias diff='colordiff'`

Answer (score 3):

Some text decoration (bold) to easily differentiate between root and non-root shell.  For Zsh:

```
if test $UID = 0
    then PS1="%B${PS1}%b "
fi
```

For Bash:

```
if test $UID = 0
    then PS1="\033[1m${PS1}\033[0m"
fi
```

Comment: Please specify your shell. The question's only shell specific tag is [tag:bash], but I feel your code is not `bash`.

Comment: @manatwork: sorry, forgot to mention that it was Zsh.  Updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

I just wondered the same thing. I have my own approach, but I'm looking for     alternatives.

I write bash wrappers around program calls and pipe their output though `sed`. What I like about `sed` is that it will modify and echo each line right away => not much buffering. However, I dislike that for every call to a wrapped program the `sed` code is parsed and compiled.

For example this is what I do to color the output of `ip`:

```
#
# Colorcodes
#
NORMAL=`echo -e '\033[0m'`
RED=`echo -e '\033[31m'`
GREEN=`echo -e '\033[0;32m'`
LGREEN=`echo -e '\033[1;32m'`
BLUE=`echo -e '\033[0;34m'`
LBLUE=`echo -e '\033[1;34m'`
YELLOW=`echo -e '\033[0;33m'`


#
# command: ip
# highlight ip addresses, default route and interface names
#

IP4=$GREEN
IP6=$LBLUE
IFACE=${YELLOW}
DEFAULT_ROUTE=$LBLUE

IP_CMD=$(which ip)

function colored_ip()
{
${IP_CMD} $@ | sed \
    -e "s/inet [^ ]\+ /${IP4}&${NORMAL}/g"\
    -e "s/inet6 [^ ]\+ /${IP6}&${NORMAL}/g"\
    -e "s/^default via .*$/${DEFAULT_ROUTE}&${NORMAL}/"\
    -e "s/^\([0-9]\+: \+\)\([^ \t]\+\)/\1${IFACE}\2${NORMAL}/"
}

alias ip='colored_ip'
```

Answer (score 3):

For setting the prompt, I have this in my .bashrc file.

```
#Set variables for foreground colors
fgRed=$(tput setaf 1)     ; fgGreen=$(tput setaf 2)  ; fgBlue=$(tput setaf 4)
fgMagenta=$(tput setaf 5) ; fgYellow=$(tput setaf 3) ; fgCyan=$(tput setaf 6)
fgWhite=$(tput setaf 7)   ; fgBlack=$(tput setaf 0)
#Set variables for background colors
bgRed=$(tput setab 1)     ; bgGreen=$(tput setab 2)  ; bgBlue=$(tput setab 4)
bgMagenta=$(tput setab 5) ; bgYellow=$(tput setab 3) ; bgCyan=$(tput setab 6)
bgWhite=$(tput setab 7)   ; bgBlack=$(tput setab 0)
#Set variables for font weight and text decoration
B=$(tput bold) ; U=$(tput smul) ; C=$(tput sgr0)
#NOTE: ${C} clears the current formatting

if [[ $USER = "root" ]]; then
  PS1="${B}${fgRed}\u${C}@\h(\s): ${fgGreen}\w${C} > "
else
  PS1="${B}${fgCyan}\u${C}@\h(\s): ${fgGreen}\w${C} > "
fi
```

This gives me a prompt that looks something like this:

```
user@host(bash): ~/bin >
```

The working directory is in green.  And the user name is bold and cyan unless I ran the shell with `sudo`, in which case the user name ("root") displays bold and red.

I personally really like having the formatting control characters stored in variables because it makes reading the code for setting the prompt easier.  It also makes editing the prompt *much* easier.

The reason I use `tput` is that it's supposed to be more universally supported than the weird `033[01;31m\]` sequences.  Also, as an added bonus, if you do `echo $PS1` at the prompt, you will see the raw prompt with **colors** instead of those unintelligible control sequences.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a project that helps on colorizing scripts output also, its named ScriptEchoColor at source forge: http://scriptechocolor.sourceforge.net/

ex.:

```
echoc "@{lr}text output in light red"
echoc "@{bLGu}text outpus in blue, light green background and underlined"
echoc "you @{lr} can @{bLGu} mix @{-a} it all too"
echoc -x "ls" #executes ls command and colorizes it automatically to be easy to be seen
```

The automatic colors are configurable.

This is an example done with it:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A great general-purpose *Python* tool for coloring the output of commands is '[colout](http://nojhan.github.io/colout/)'

You give it a regex with N groups, followed by a comma separated list of N colors. Any text that matches a group will be displayed in the corresponding color.

So for example, if you're looking at some test output:

```
python -m unittest discover -v
```

[image: Uncolored output of some Python unittests]

then you can spruce it up with:

```
python -m unittest discover -v 2>&1 | colout '(.*ERROR$)|(.*FAIL$)|(\(.*\))' red,yellow,black bold
```

[image: Colored output of some Python unittests]

See how my regex has three groups (the parenthesis) followed by three colors (and optionally three styles, but I've used a shorthand to set all the colors to 'bold', so the 'black' group, which matches text in brackets, comes out as dark grey.)

Note also how I had to add `2>&1` to the end of the Python invocation, because the output of unittest is on stderr, so I transferred it to stdout so that I could pipe it into colout.

This is generally so easy to use that I often find myself creating new colout invocations on-the-fly, and reusing or modifying them from my command-line history.

The only downside of it is that it comes as a Python package, not a standalone executable, so you need to install it using pip, or `sudo python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 2):

I find Solarized useful. Its a neat project with uniform colors for lots of applications.

http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized
https://github.com/altercation/solarized

Answer (score 2):

I use [color wrapper](http://cwrapper.sourceforge.net/).

> cw is a non-intrusive real-time ANSI color wrapper for common unix-based
>   commands on GNU/linux.  cw is designed to simulate the environment of the
>   commands being executed, so that if a person types 'du', 'df', 'ping', etc.
>   in their shell it will automatically color the output in real-time according
>   to a definition file containing the color format desired.  cw has support for
>   wildcard match coloring, tokenized coloring, headers/footers, case scenario
>   coloring, command line dependent definition coloring, and includes over 50
>   pre-made definition files.

It is almost seamless, but once i found that ps in interactive shell returns different output comparing ps in a pipe.

Comment: This sounded promising, but the colors are random at every invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my cf for file name coloring on the command line, it's a quick little awk-based colorizer that works via pipes - coloring filenames in Truecolor sRGB.

It's got a brightly colored default configuration and unlike ls it does 
not suffer a performance penalty for adding new colors. (ls must scan the 
entire LS_COLORS string for each miss).

https://github.com/AdamDanischewski/cf

[image: cf usage]

[image: cf screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For Mac you can use following as specified [here](https://superuser.com/questions/335471/using-colour-schemes-with-vim-and-putty)

```
if [ "$TERM" = xterm ]; then TERM=xterm-256color; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to do it on log files.

```
tail -f example.log | sed \
-e "s/FATAL/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/ERROR/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/WARNING/"$'\e[33m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/INFO/"$'\e[32m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/DEBUG/"$'\e[34m'"&"$'\e[m'"/"
```

An example of it working and screenshot below:

```
echo " [timestamp] production.FATAL Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.ERROR Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.WARNING Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.INFO Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.DEBUG Some Message\n"  | sed \
-e "s/FATAL/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/ERROR/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/WARNING/"$'\e[33m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/INFO/"$'\e[32m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/DEBUG/"$'\e[34m'"&"$'\e[m'"/"
```

Prints out like this on Mac:

[image: Mac sed logs to add colour]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your `vim` colorful just like me, I suggest you to follow two steps:

1. learn how to turn on the feature by following this link: [turn on
   color syntax highlighting in vi or vim](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-or-off-color-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-or-vim/).

> key steps in the link:
>
> 1. Edit ~/.vimrc file by typing the command: ***vi ~/.vimrc***
> 2. Append the following option:***syntax on***
> 3. Save and close the file
> 4. Test it by running vim command: ***vim foo.sh***

2. find a color scheme you like, and use it. The scheme which I use:[the scheme that I am using](https://github.com/hdima/python-syntax)

Comment: When using links to external source, you should check the "Provide context for links" part (Quote important parts) of the relevant part of the guide: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

If bash is your choice, I recommend [oh-my-bash](https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash). If zsh is your choice, I recommend [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). Both support colorization of your terminal and different output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to humbly advertise [my recent publication](https://github.com/jamadagni/textattr/) of `ta` or **textattr**, a library and command-line tool that aims to make adding color and attributes to beautify the terminal output of your program easier by translating human-readable specs into ANSI escape codes.

For example:

`echo "The Git repo $(ta yellow)${CUR_REPO}$(ta off) is $(ta green)up-to-date$(ta off)"`

or the even shorter:

`echo "The Git repo $(ta y)${CUR_REPO}$(ta f) is $(ta g)up-to-date$(ta f)"`

or an alternate:

`tawrite "The Git repo " @y ${CUR_REPO} @f " is " @g up-to-date @f "\n"`

will give you something like:

[image]

Currently this library is usable from four languages C, C++, D and Python apart from commandline use from your favourite shell.

Note that it does not automatically colourize the output of any other programs. It is rather a utility to help you with not having to remember the abstruse codes. You only need to use the obvious colour names or their easy-to-remember **rgb cmyk w(hite) (of)f** abbreviations.

For more details visit [the textattr repo](https://github.com/jamadagni/textattr/).

Answer (score 0):

For awesome colorization of diff you should take a look at https://github.com/dandavison/delta

You just [install](https://github.com/dandavison/delta#installation) it and then you add this to `.gitconfig`

```
[pager]
    diff = delta
    log = delta
    reflog = delta
    show = delta

[interactive]
    diffFilter = delta --color-only --features=interactive
```

Then you get syntax highlighting in your diffs

[image: syntax highlighted diff]

Answer (score 0):

Use the colors before the parts you want to color. This is where I found this [gist.github.com/vratiu/9780109](https://gist.github.com/vratiu/9780109).

```
# Reset
Color_Off="\[\033[0m\]"       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
Black="\[\033[0;30m\]"        # Black
Red="\[\033[0;31m\]"          # Red
Green="\[\033[0;32m\]"        # Green
Yellow="\[\033[0;33m\]"       # Yellow
Blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"         # Blue
Purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"       # Purple
Cyan="\[\033[0;36m\]"         # Cyan
White="\[\033[0;37m\]"        # White

# Bold
BBlack="\[\033[1;30m\]"       # Black
BRed="\[\033[1;31m\]"         # Red
BGreen="\[\033[1;32m\]"       # Green
BYellow="\[\033[1;33m\]"      # Yellow
BBlue="\[\033[1;34m\]"        # Blue
BPurple="\[\033[1;35m\]"      # Purple
BCyan="\[\033[1;36m\]"        # Cyan
BWhite="\[\033[1;37m\]"       # White

# Underline
UBlack="\[\033[4;30m\]"       # Black
URed="\[\033[4;31m\]"         # Red
UGreen="\[\033[4;32m\]"       # Green
UYellow="\[\033[4;33m\]"      # Yellow
UBlue="\[\033[4;34m\]"        # Blue
UPurple="\[\033[4;35m\]"      # Purple
UCyan="\[\033[4;36m\]"        # Cyan
UWhite="\[\033[4;37m\]"       # White

# Background
On_Black="\[\033[40m\]"       # Black
On_Red="\[\033[41m\]"         # Red
On_Green="\[\033[42m\]"       # Green
On_Yellow="\[\033[43m\]"      # Yellow
On_Blue="\[\033[44m\]"        # Blue
On_Purple="\[\033[45m\]"      # Purple
On_Cyan="\[\033[46m\]"        # Cyan
On_White="\[\033[47m\]"       # White

# High Intensity
IBlack="\[\033[0;90m\]"       # Black
IRed="\[\033[0;91m\]"         # Red
IGreen="\[\033[0;92m\]"       # Green
IYellow="\[\033[0;93m\]"      # Yellow
IBlue="\[\033[0;94m\]"        # Blue
IPurple="\[\033[0;95m\]"      # Purple
ICyan="\[\033[0;96m\]"        # Cyan
IWhite="\[\033[0;97m\]"       # White

# Bold High Intensity
BIBlack="\[\033[1;90m\]"      # Black
BIRed="\[\033[1;91m\]"        # Red
BIGreen="\[\033[1;92m\]"      # Green
BIYellow="\[\033[1;93m\]"     # Yellow
BIBlue="\[\033[1;94m\]"       # Blue
BIPurple="\[\033[1;95m\]"     # Purple
BICyan="\[\033[1;96m\]"       # Cyan
BIWhite="\[\033[1;97m\]"      # White

# High Intensty backgrounds
On_IBlack="\[\033[0;100m\]"   # Black
On_IRed="\[\033[0;101m\]"     # Red
On_IGreen="\[\033[0;102m\]"   # Green
On_IYellow="\[\033[0;103m\]"  # Yellow
On_IBlue="\[\033[0;104m\]"    # Blue
On_IPurple="\[\033[10;95m\]"  # Purple
On_ICyan="\[\033[0;106m\]"    # Cyan
On_IWhite="\[\033[0;107m\]"   # White

# Various variables you might want for your PS1 prompt instead
Time12h="\T"
Time12a="\@"
PathShort="\w"
PathFull="\W"
NewLine="\n"
```

Remember to keep color to yes in `.bashrc` file and the color does not change back so end your colored part with `"\[\033[0m\]"`.

Comment: Use the colors before the parts you want to color.
This is where i found this
https://gist.github.com/vratiu/9780109

Comment: Please [edit] and add additional info into the answer and **not** in the comments, that is not what they are for. Also, using code formatting would vastly improve the presentation of your answer.