# Where is the `$TERM` environmental variable set in Debian Jessie for console logins?

Tags: debian, terminal, systemd, environment-variables, console

I have read a lot of articles and SE questions regarding how and where the default `$TERM` environmental variable gets set.

Unfortunately in Debian 8.1 I can't seem to find where the default `$TERM` variable is set when logging in to the system from `tty1`.

I would love to be pointed in the right direction if this is indeed a duplicate question but the following questions didn't seem like they provided an answer:

[tmux, TERM and 256 colours support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118806/tmux-term-and-256-colours-support)

[Where does the TERM environment variable default get set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198794/where-does-the-term-environment-variable-default-get-set)

[Is it correct to set the $TERM variable manually?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108410/is-it-correct-to-set-the-term-variable-manually)

### Edit

When I log in via `tty1` here is what `$TERM` is set to:

```
$> echo $TERM
linux
```

Listing of `/usr/lib/systemd/`, note that there is no `system` directory here.

```
$> ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Aug 19 13:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 44 root root 4096 Aug 20 14:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 19 13:37 catalog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 26 02:07 network
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 19 13:37 ntp-units.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 19 13:37 user
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 26 02:07 user-generators
```

Comment: The second [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198794/where-does-the-term-environment-variable-default-get-set) did say that right . On `systemd` systems, one can see this in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` unit file, which reads
`Environment=TERM=linux`

Comment: @neuron Yeah I thought that might be where it should be but see my edits to the question. That file does not seem to exist on this system. FWIW it was a fresh installation of 8.1.

Comment: Yup, @yaegashi is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose `TERM` is set to `linux` for the init process (pid 1) by Linux kernel [here](https://sources.debian.net/src/linux/3.16.7-ckt11-1/init/main.c/#L163) and [there](https://sources.debian.net/src/linux/3.16.7-ckt11-1/init/main.c/#L906).  You can see it in `/proc/1/environ` (sorry the following output is from Ubuntu 15.04):

```
$ sudo strings /proc/1/environ 
HOME=/
init=/sbin/init
recovery=
TERM=linux
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic.efi.signed
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
rootmnt=/root
```

On Debian/Ubuntu systemd based systems it gets propagated to child getty processes by definitions in `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`.

```
[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
```

So you might be able to override `TERM` in the kernel command line.  Try to edit `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub` and reboot.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="TERM=vt100"
```

Comment: Thanks, the file I was looking for was `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` and your suggestion for modifying the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` works nicely to change this. The system is running on embedded hardware so there will only be one serial console. Thanks.

Comment: @111--- As of 2024 (since when?) systemd sets the serial console $TERM based on `/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` . e.g.: One needs to add `Environment=TERM=linux` at the start of the `[Service]` section

Answer (score -1):

The $TERM variable is normally set in 
/etc/profile or .bashrc depends on the distro ur using.

Read http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-11.html

Comment: `/etc/profile` just sets `$PATH` and `$PS1` and my `.bashrc` does not seem to explicitly set the `$TERM` variable.

Comment: What is the content of /etc/profile.d/ ?
Can u find with cat and grep on TERM to see if there are files/scripts that sets the environment for TERM ?

Comment: Debian does not do this. It also does not make sense to do so, since your shell has no information whatsoever what the right value should be.