# Run script on non-full bash-login invoked as "sh"

Tags: bash, shell, login, su

I'm currently trying to modify my terminal to have the prompt displayed in a different colour than the whole rest of the shell, and I would like to make it white for normal users and red for root.
I would like to do so on both, an OS X 10.10 Desktop and an Ubuntu 14.10 Server.
The only way I know of doing this is to modify `$PS1`.
And to do so, I would have to put it in a script that the shell sources on login, right?

However, on OS X the root user's shell is `/bin/sh`, and although that is actually bash, it does not source any login script unless a full login is invoked.
Now I know about `su - <user>`, but I need it to work with just `su <user>`.
I **could** change the root user's login shell, but I'd **rather not**.

Here's what I found out so far:

`bash` invoked as `bash` and logged in as `su -` sources:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~/.profile
```

`bash` invoked as `bash` and logged in as `su` sources:

```
~/.bashrc
```

`bash` invoked as `sh` and logged in as `su -` sources:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~/.profile
```

`bash` invoked as `sh` and logged in as `su` sources nothing at all.

I also tried hijacking `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, but that gets emptied on invoking `su`.

On the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) it says:

> **Invoked with name sh**
>
> If Bash is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of `sh` as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.
>
> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, in that order. The `--noprofile` option may be used to inhibit this behavior. When invoked as an interactive shell with the name `sh`, Bash looks for the variable `ENV`, expands its value if it is defined, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Since a shell invoked as `sh` does not attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup files, the `--rcfile` option has no effect. A non-interactive shell invoked with the name `sh` does not attempt to read any other startup files.
>
> When invoked as `sh`, Bash enters POSIX mode after the startup files are read.

So... is there any way me to set `$ENV`?
Simply setting it before invoking `su` has no effect.

Or is there any other way for me to modify `$PS1` when the UID changes (full login or not), without having to use `su - ...`, changing the root user's login shell or messing with `su`/`bash`?

Comment: I presume you meant to write “bash invoked as `sh` and logged in as **`su`** [not `su -`] sources nothing at all”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su -c bash
```

Make an alias if that's too much typing for you.

You've correctly analyzed that a plain `su` doesn't load any initialization file, so either you need to change the configuration or you need to change the command.

Comment: Well, in that case... looks like root is gonna get a new login shell.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use that on my Mac and it's also working on my Ubuntu Server. But I edited two files.

In the .profile of root I put

```
PS1="\[\033[1;31m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\h \[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[m\] \$ " # Root
```

and in the .bash_profile of my personal user I put

```
PS1="\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\h \[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[m\] \$ " # User
```

The effect is the following :

[image: My Terminal]
You can find all colors here http://blog.taylormcgann.com/tag/prompt-color/

But in your case, I think you should use this solution  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174/50145

Comment: `.profile` isn't read by a plain `su`, that's the whole point of the question.