# Terminal prompt overwrites current line

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, bashrc

I have an issue with my terminal prompt line. When the line is too long it wraps on the same line and then <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> makes it look even worse.

I have already checked [Terminal prompt not wrapping correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly),
but it looks like I am apparently closing all the squared brackets for non printable characters.

This is my PS1:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }\[\033[01;36m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]\033[01;34m\]\w\033[00m\][$(type __git_ps1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && __git_ps1 "(%s)")]
```

Consider this as my standard prompt line

```
MELISC@work~/dev/bin_tools[((main))]
```

I was able to get

```
assdasdasdasdasdadasdsadadasdaddasdadadasdadsadasdsa((main))] asdsadsadsadsadasdasdassdasdasdassdasdassdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsad
```

I have already checked my `.bashrc`

I have and `shopt -s checkwinsize` should autocheck the columns

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've completely banjanxed the Bourne Again shell's idea of what's been printed and what it has to erase/rewrite as it displays command history and lets you edit the command line.

Breaking your prompt down into sections:

1. `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]` — non-printing characters, properly enclosed
2. `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }` — printing characters only, presumably
3. `\[\033[01;36m\]` — non-printing characters, properly enclosed
4. `\u@\h` — printing characters only
5. `\[\033[00m\]` — non-printing characters, properly enclosed
6. `\033[01;34m\]` — non-printing characters, improperly enclosed so the Bourne Again shell does not know that they are
7. `\w\033[00m\]` — an erroneous mixture of printing and non-printing characters
8. `[$(type __git_ps1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && __git_ps1 "(%s)")]`  — printing characters only, presumably

[I've given this advice before](https://superuser.com/a/695350/38062), but it is general advice that applies here as well:

- Use either `\e` or `\033` consistently, for your own sanity.
- Make your `\[` and `\]` strictly matching non-nesting pairs.
- Make sure that *all* non-printing sequences are within `\[` and `\]` (and that, conversely, that all printing sequences are not).

(This is why I personally prefer the Z Shell and its alternative prompt expansion mechanism for when I want wacky coloured prompts.  It *knows* that things like `%F{green}` aren't printing sequences, without having to be told; and it also works out the correct escape sequences from `terminfo`, without having them hardwired.)

Comment: Thanks a lot I modified my PS1 in `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }\[\e[01;36m\]\u@\h\[\e[00m\]\[\e[01;34m\]\w\[\e[00m\][$(type __git_ps1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && __git_ps1 "(%s)")]
` and now it is perfectly working!
I had never really understood how that thing worked until I read you explanation.

Comment: +1 for the use of `banjanxed`

Comment: This helped to me to solve a ~17y old mystery: https://twitter.com/sskras/status/1383364210088808458 ! Thanks a LOT, Jonathan!

Answer (score 0):

While JdeBP's answer is excellent, I thought I'd add the one that worked for me since my PS1 was already proper. I originally posted this on a related Issue ([#2713](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2713#issuecomment-530975323)) on the WSL repo on GitHub:

---

I'd like to add a not here for posterity, because this issue has been driving me nuts. I think I finally found the cause, at least for me, so hopefully this helps others. I have seen this issue on various systems (builds 18362 - 18975) with various distros. I ensured 100% the syntax of my PS1 in my .bashrc was correct and all non-printing characters were properly escaped etc.

The issue for me was with the Console Properties. I installed my WSL distros (Ubuntu, Debian, and Kali) through the Microsoft Store, and ran the apps from my Start Menu. This launches WSL in a Linux branded classic Windows Command Prompt console as I understand. (BTW, launching from a folder with Shift+Right-click / "Open linux shell here" opens the same Console window).

Whatever the case, the point is when you right-click the resulting console title bar, click Properties, then select the option to "Wrap text output on resize" this is what resolved the issue for me.

[image: Console Properties]

[image: Wrap Text]

Now I can properly enter commands that wrap around to the next line and can move my cursor around appropriately. This is definitely a bug somewhere, but I don't know where the fault lies.