# Where to put the escape characters?

Tags: terminal, colors, prompt, bashrc

I've tried to change my prompt by editing .bashrc:

```
export PS1="\e[0;32m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m"
```

This seems to work, but ctrl-r to access reverse history ends up with my typing not appearing in the same place as it will be interpreted (like [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/224306/why-does-ctrl-r-act-weirdly-showing-only-part-of-a-command-on-os-x)). It is fine when using the up or down arrows to select previous commands though.

I've had a look at that question, but can't seem to work out where to apply the escape characters in my prompt. I've tried a few combinations but then I break normal text typing functionality or simple back/forwards through history.

If you could include an explanation of which instances of characters need escaping and why, that would help me (and hopefully others) learn.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/ , http://superuser.com/questions/695338/ , and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell needs to know how much space the prompt takes up on screen. Any character sequence which takes up no space on screen needs to be escaped using `\[` and `\]`: this includes escape sequences such as those used to set the colour, or give the terminal window a title, or move the cursor...

Thus in your case:

```
export PS1="\[\e[0;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[m\]"
```

tells the shell that only `[\u@\h \W]$` actually take up space on the screen.

Comment: Ah great - that makes a lot of sense. The other question didn't really offer that level of explanation of the _why_.