# Copy/paste doesn't work properly when changing prompt colors

Tags: colors, prompt

Open a prompt, try to do this:

- type this code: `export PS1="\e[1;30m-30-\e[m >"`
- copy it with your mouse (select the code + copy it (I have auto-copy when I select with the mouse enabled))
- close the prompt
- open a brand new prompt
- immediately paste it (SHIFT INS)
- type "HOME" key and "END" key, you'll see the cursor go to logical positions (start and end of the code)
- now press ENTER
- you prompt changes the colors
- immediately paste it (SHIFT INS)
- type "HOME" key and "END" key, you'll see the cursor go to *illogical* positions (offset problem)

This means if I apply colors to the prompt I can't copy/paste + change my copied code...

NB: I'm asking it here because I thought it was a problem of [wsltty here](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/134) but it seems it's only related to what I'm trying to assign: `export PS1="\e[1;30m-30-\e[m >"`... and I dont see a problem. It should just change the colors of the prompt (and that's what it does actually). But it seems it does something more I dont see. Does somebody know what it could be?

Comment: What shell are you doing this in? I can't reproduce any issue in `bash` (or I'm not able to follow your instructions).

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/ again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose escape sequences in pairs of `\[` and `\]` or you'll have that offset problem.

Comment: May I ask you to add in your answer the working version of `export PS1="\e[1;30m-30-\e[m >"` so I can make the link? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

user1274247 is right, you need to enclose escape sequences.

Here's what my PS1 looks like.

```
\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]
```