# How to fix HOME and END buttons in Bash with ANSI prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ansi

In bash, whenever I have a prompt with ANSI color codes, it messes up the HOME and END functionality.  Is there an obvious fix for this?

To re-create:

```
PS1="\e[0;33m\u@\e[m $ "
echo "This is a very long sentence to demonstrate what im talking about"
(press UP)
(press HOME)
```

See where the cursor ends up?

[image]

- Ubuntu 16.04
- This is a remote login.  Is this an SSH problem?  Doesn't seem to be. I've tried numerous SSH terminals and VNC from both Mac and PC, all giving same results.

Comment: shouldn't you put the `\e[...m` color escapes inside `\[...\]`?

Comment: BINGO - that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317734/5132 is a better duplicate.