# Kali Linux - QTerminal visual issues

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, virtualbox, terminal-emulator, bugs

I just fresh installed Kali 2020.2 and I like their redesign and move to Xfce. However, I noticed fairly quickly that the terminal is causing me issues. I recorded my screen to show the problem, as it's tough to explain:

[image: animated GIF illustrating the below]

Basically if I type a long string, it will wrap around and type over the prompt. In addition, when I use the up arrow to look at my history of commands, it will eventually keep a portion of an old command and then lock up the terminal. I have also seen it add crazy space.

Is there anything I can do to help resolve this? Here is some information about my setup:

1. I am using VirtualBox.
2. I am using Kali 2020.2, installed from its ISO.

Comment: I generally use the word "banjanxed" to find https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317734/5132 when people duplicate this question.

Comment: You are a godsend--thanks. It was impossible to figure out how to search for this... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) for the [explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/terminal-prompt-overwrites-current-line) to solve this at version 2020.2 of Kali Linux

You have to modify your .bashrc file at sections:

1. `prompt_color=$'\033[01;34m'` to `prompt_color=$'\[\033[01;34m\]'`
2. `path_color=$'\033[01;32m'` to `path_color=$'\[\033[01;32m\]'`
3. `prompt_color=$'\033[01;31m'` to `prompt_color=$'\[\033[01;31m\]'`
4. `path_color=$'\033[01;34m'` to `path_color=$'\[\033[01;34m\]'`

(It's just add `\[` before `\033`)

Then add an export of PS1 at end of .bashrc

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${prompt_color}\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:${path_color}\w\[\033[00m\]\$"
```

Comment: This didn't quite work... BUT I did go to the linked explanation and borrowed the updated PS1 variable used by the OP and it fixed it! This reminds me that I need to learn more about advanced color prompts...

Comment: Should this be reported as a bug to Kali?

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot that I had exported PS1 too, i will edit the answer, to export PS1 as come default with Kali 2020.2. Thanks! And yep, should be reported ASAP, it was too difficult to find this answer

Comment: I think someone report it before: [Link](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=6586). This has been fixed with kali-defaults 2020.3.4