# After adding a custom prompt in my .bashrc, the typing seems to repeat in the second line

Tags: bash, prompt

So I edited my .bashrc and decided to add the following code:

```
bold=$(tput bold);
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    PS1="\[${bold}\e[38;2;171;178;191m[\e[m\]";
    PS1+="\[${bold}\e[38;2;97;175;239m\u\e[m\]";
    PS1+="\[${bold}\e[38;2;152;195;121m@\e[m\]";
    PS1+="\[${bold}\e[38;2;198;120;221m\h: \e[m\]";
    PS1+="\[${bold}\e[38;2;86;182;194m\w\e[m\]";
    PS1+="\[${bold}\e[38;2;171;178;191m]\e[m\]";
    PS1+="\[${bold}\e[38;2;229;192;123m$ \e[m\]";


else
    PS1="\[${bold}\e[38;2;224;108;117m[\u@\h \W]# \e[m\]";
fi
```

After doing so, the colours are working just fine however, after a quarter of the second line is completed, it sort goes back to the start of the second line and overwrites whatever was written over there and the moves on. I'm sure this is some sort of syntax error on my part, not sure what it is.

Comment: This is probably because you keep adding the bold and never turn it off, but what is the final PS1 you are trying to create?

Comment: This is pretty much https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317734/5132 again.

Comment: Could you try and explain what the prompt should actually look like, what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve [username@hostname: ~]$ where the username, @, hostname and the two brackets and $ are in different colours