# Problems in linux xterm/rxvt/console under SSH after migrating to UTF-8

Tags: bash, console, character-encoding, inputrc

I use bash and have been using Latin1 encoding my whole life, since I've always had problems when trying to migrate to the advised UTF-8. I finally gave up, and I am migrating everything to UTF-8. What a pain...

I have a specific problem when doing SSH with all `rxvt`, `urxvt` and `xterm`. My remote prompt is set as:

```
 PS1="\033[32m\[\h:\W> \]\033[0m"
```

This shows a nice green thing like

```
 MyBox:~>
```

After migrating to utf-8 (all lang and locales from `en_US` to `en_US.UTF-8`), my `UP`, `DOWN` arrows (back/forward history), `DEL` and `BS` don't get track of the position in the line (destroying the prompt, deleting the wrong letters, etc). A mess. Example:

```
Orion:~> ssh me@MyBox.mydomain...
Last login: Sat Oct  3 13:47:42 2020 from NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN
MyBox:~> ls
amp/  ap/  bin/  phantomjs/  varios/
MyBox:~>
```

After hitting `UP` several times to go backwards in history, it reads:

```
MyBox:~vi .basrc
```

instead of

```
MyBox:~> vi .basrc
```

so some characters vanished. This makes a mess to edit a command line, for example.

I tried fiddling with the `~/.inputrc` file in the remote SSH machine without luck. It seems the shortcuts are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317734/5132 again.

Comment: @JdeBP why not flag this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-setting the prompt. The `\[` ... `\]` segment should enclose the *non*-printing characters, but in yours it encloses only the printing characters. (This is nothing to do with Latin1 vs UTF-8, you'll be reassured to know.)

Try this instead

```
PS1="\[\033[32m\]\h:\W> \[\033[0m\]"
```

See the `PROMPTING` section in the shell manual (`man bash` in my case) for the details.

Comment: Indeed, this is working much better (not sure if the problem is solved, though). But why I didn't have the problem when working in ISO8859-1 environment?

Comment: Luck, maybe...?