# Help with bash colours and long lines

Tags: bash, prompt

When I write a long command and the line of text gets to end of terminal, it continues at beginning the same line (as if it was "overwriting it), and if I hit `home` it doesn't really go to the beginning of the line.

I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67828/problem-to-write-long-lines-in-terminal), [this other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/terminal-prompt-overwrites-current-line), etc., and I now it is related with the colors and things I want it to display... and I am so sorry to open another post, but I tried to edit the line myself but I can't really get it ok. Can yo guys give me some help?

Here is the extract from my `.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\][\u@debian]\[\033[01;34m\][\033[01;34m\]\w\]]\033[01;34m\]\$\033[00m\] '
```

To clarify it, I want the prompt to be:

`[username@debian][~]$`

- Meaning, username@debian between brackets `[\u@debian]`, in green color

*Yes, I want it to display "debian", not usual `\h`

- Working directory also between its brackets `[\w]`, in blue color
- The `$` of normal user
- And the text I type to be displayed in white colour.

- I don't care about root user's prompt.

Thanks for the help, and again, sorry to open another post for this...

---

Edit: I tried to rewrite it after slowly reading [this full tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/). But wasn't able to make it work. Now it doesn't "overwrite" the first line, but on the second, after a few characters, overwrites that second line for just a few characters, then continues ok. But with this new PS1, if I hit the `UP` arrow on the keyboard to previous commands, it gets really funky.

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\[[\]\u\[@debian]\]\[\033[01;34m\]\[[\]\w\[]\]\[\033[01;34m\]\$\[\033[00m\] '
```

If I didn't get wrong the tutorial, it is supposed to be:

- `\[` Begin a sequence of non-printing characters.
- `\]` end the sequence of non-printing characters.
- `\033[XXm` color, that needed to be between the start and end of non-printing characters, so, for example, for color blue (34) it should be: `\[\033[34m\]`

So, in my mind, it should work now, but it doesn't. Clearly I'm not seeing it right -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo here:

> ```
> \[\033[01;34m\][\033[01;34m\]
>                ^
> ```

That `[` ought to be `\[`.

The `\[`...`\]` markers tell Bash that those portions of the string don't contribute to column count.

Comment: I seem to lose the `[` before the working directory, meaning it shows `[user@debian] ~] $` (I use spaces here so it's easier to read, but the characters are, of course, all next to each other)


Here is [a screenshot](https://ibb.co/qDZFqgH)

Comment: Perhaps you wanted both `\[` and `[`, then, each in the appropriate place.  `[` where you want a literal `[`, and `\[` around each of the control sequences: `[\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]]`?  You might find it easier to define some variables, e.g. `green='\['"$(tput setaf 2)"'\]'` etc.

Comment: I tried the suggested string `[\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]]`, but it doesn't seem to work. I've edited the main post with another try starting from scratch. Maybe you can help from that now

Comment: I think you're getting really confused.  For example `\[[\]` is completely broken - you've told Bash that `[` doesn't take any screen space.  There's one simple rule - use `\[`..`\]` around *sequences that don't advance the cursor*, and nowhere else.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! I completely misunderstood everything!! `\[`...`\]` should have been only for the colors! I LOVE YOU SO MUCH!