# How to set the default color of output / things typed in Bash

Tags: bash, colors

When I am typing or viewing text on my terminal, the color is white. Any command after I type my prompt is white, and the default output (`stdout`) is white.

I looked and my terminal emulator does not have any direct controls for "default foreground color".

How can I change this color?
[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment) only explains how to change it for certain programs and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/957248/how-to-change-bash-default-foreground-color) only answers for the "Terminator" program.  I would like to set this as a default for all terminal emulators I am using.

For instance, if I end my `PS1` variable with an ANSI color code, then what I initially type will have that color, however this does not carry over for other things output to `stdout`.

Comment: It does, though, carry over.  However, it can very easily be overridden.  For example, if your `PS1` leaves the text as bright green, and your `ls` is colorized, then when you `ls`, that bright green will persist right up until the next color change.  The only "work-around" for this is, like with the program-specific guides you already reference, to redefine what "non-bold white" looks like, as that is the default color.

Comment: I see. How would I redefine "non-bold-white"?

Comment: @Startec That is a terminal-specific option.  Most terminal emulators have options to change these colors, but it is not something you can do in Bash itself

Comment: What is this terminal emulator?

Comment: I use a few. Mosh for chrome and the Linux subsystem for windows are the two main ones.